# Zathura with Latexmk on MacOS

Tags: macos, vim, latex, pdf-reader

I am trying to get my LaTeX setup up and running:
Vim with vimtex -> Latexmk -> Zathura

I installed everything through HomeBrew.

```
$ zathura -v
zathura 0.3.7
(plugin) pdf-poppler (0.2.7)
$ tlmgr info latexmk
...
installed:   Yes
revision:    43099
...
cat-version: 4.52c
cat-date:    2017-01-30 14:23:03 +0100
```

Vimtex is install via vim-plug, though this info should not be important.

Now Zathura, by default, utilizes glib to detect file changes for auto-reload. But glib, even when compiled from source, does not seem to work. I am hence trying to find an alternative way of reloading Zathura view.

I tried setting

```
$pdf_viewer = 'zathura'
$pdf_update_method = 2
```

in `.latexmkrc` and

```
set filemonitor "signal"
```

in `zathurarc`.

I still cannot get the automatic refresh of Zathura view to work. The compilation is all good, as pressing `R` manually in Zathura refreshes to the new change no problem.

My question is about making Zathura reload on recompliation by latexmk.
Would you have any ideas on where to move on for the auto-refresh bypassing glib?

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to set up a similar situation and came across your question in my search at the same problem with zathura.  I am going to apologize in advance, because this does not meet your specified requirements as stated (using the same software packages) however they are all open free brew installable packages.

I found something that works properly for me and thought i'd share it with you in case it meets your needs.

pandoc, skim, vim and vim plugins

vim-auto-save + pandoc-preview.vim --> Skim.app

Technically, vim-auto-save is not necessary, but I wanted something that would reload my pdf everytime I left insert mode.

but this gives the autoloading functionality i think we are both looking for.

`Plug 'lynnard/pandoc-preview.vim'`
`Plug '907th/vim-auto-save'`

The Skim App can be opened with

`$ open -a Skim filename.pdf`

You'll also want to run

`$ defaults write -app Skim SKAutoReloadFileUpdate -boolean true`

to stop the app from giving you an alert message every time the file is changed.

open `Skim` for the first time, got to `Preferences --> Sync --> Check for file changes`

for your `.vimrc` or `init.vim` (if neovim), you can add these preferences for the autosave plugin:

`let g:auto_save = 1  " enable AutoSave on Vim startup"
let g:auto_save_events = ["InsertLeave"]`

Sorry that it doesn't meet your exact reqs, hope having another option is of use.  Good luck.